# How to 'A' UNITY3D apk file android 'B' application data exchange

Tags: android

Create the android application.
 "A" apk file and other applications of B Data communications.

For the purpose of providing data
"A" android apk file Unity3D files and applications through B
Data and will be able to run.

Writing articles because they did not know how to use my application to the Android ...
Encourage you to let us know the link or the description of the site on this issue for some information or samples.